# What the function of the pronoun"it" here, does it refer to the contractor because the author did not know precisely what the contractor's gender is?

Tags: pronouns, it-its-itself

To the extent that the Contractor believes **it** is entitled to additional payment (there can sometimes be a dispute as to what is meant by ‘additional’) then **it** is required to make a claim in accordance with sub-clause 20.1.

What the function of the pronoun *it* here? Does it refer to the contractor because the author did not know what the contractor's gender is?

Comment: The Contractor may be a company.

Comment: if the author did not know actually what the contractor gender is, what options he has to write as a pronoun?

Comment: If that's your *actual* question here, it's been asked before.

Comment: Thank you Dan for quick response,

Comment: As Andrew implies, 'it' can just about be justified, synechdoche/menonymy ... being used, but this is a strained usage in this example. More normal would be 'they' covering man/woman/people (and conveniently always taking 'believes they are').

Comment: It sounds to me as if the contractor is not a sole trader but a commercial entity such as a company, in which case "it" is fine.